# Could synchronized have been an annotation?

Tags: java

Would it have been bad if, instead of `synchronized` keyword we had `@Synchronized` annotation? Would an annotation be more natural in this case (because you can override a `synchronized` method with a non-synchronized method - thus `synchronized` says nothing about the method itself but rather specifies something in addition to the method (that the method is guarded in a certain way), so it's not really a keyword?)

Comment: Seems pretty overly theoretical for SO and without a real answer.

Comment: @Jeff A practical reason I had a superclass with synchronized methods then forgot to make the same methods synchronized in a subclass. That of course was a very bad (as usual) design of mine but then I thought how strange I think we can not omit  any other keywords if we override methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synchronized transforms practically directly into monitorenter/monitorexit on the byte code level. And you specify what to synchronized on, you can't do that with an annotation:

```
synchronized (myLock) {
}
```

So it makes perfect sense to me that it is a keyword.

Comment: So then synchronized is not a keyword but a funny way to specify function argument (the argument being a block of code) otherwise impossible in Java ?

Comment: +1 for the bytecode mention (which means it's _not_ equivalent to a method call).

Comment: @Frank Pavageau Can you, possibly,  elaborate a bit?

Comment: @Alex I'm not an expert on bytecode or JVM internals, but here's how I see it: the fact that there is a specific instruction for entering a monitor (or exiting) allows the JVM to generate/execute very specific code, instead of special-casing a method call. Since a lock already has performance implications, I think adding a (real) method call would have amplified the problem. Anyway, since the number of opcodes is limited, I think the designers thought a bit about it before adding 2 specific instructions. :-)

Comment: @Alex If there were methods to do synchronized's job, it would only add more headaches. You would then need to enclose each block also with a try-finally clause to ensure you properly exit the monitor when the code aborts abruptly.

Answer (score 4):

synchronized is used on blocks of code and you can't add an annotation to a block of code.

You could have `@synchronized` on methods or even classes but Java didn't support annotations when Java was first introduced.

I think its important enough to deserves its own keyword. ;)

Comment: You are saying important enough to deserve a keyword, yet, can a function be so important as to be transformed into a keyword, we probably could have Object.startSynchronize(lock) and endSynchronize(lock) ?

Comment: The problem with using lock() and unlock() is you add risk that you could forget to unlock and so you need to add a try/finally block as you do with Lock (but with the added complexity its more error prone)  With closures this issue should be reduced but that is in Java 8 and it probably won't be as efficient and clean as it could be for versions to come.

Answer (score 2):

It would be cool but annotation cannot completely substitute the `synchronized` keyword: there are synchronized blocks that cannot be marked with annotation.

Moreover synchronized block accepts the monitor used for synchronization. It can be supplied dynamically that gives us certain flexibility. Annotations do not allow this since all parameters must be supplied at compile time.

Comment: Then was it a strange decision to have a keyword to do a job of a function ? Could we probably have something like Object.synchronize(Object lock) would it have been the same? I mean, synchronized is probably not really a keyword?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly as the method version of synchronized, yes.  But the other use of synchronized allows you to specify the monitor you're synchronizing on.

```
public void someMethod()
{
  synchronized(this)
  {
    //sync code
  }
  //unsynced code.
}
```